# Unclear how to write custom walker for wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to accomplish two things with a walker for wp_nav_menu:

1. I would like the unordered list to be `<ul id="my_list_id"
   role="navigation">` instead of `<ul id="my_list_id"
   class="navigation">` (Or maybe both role and class?)
2. I'd like to wrap the unordered list with `<!-googleon: all->` and
   `<!-googleoff: all->`

Honestly, the code for a custom walker is tough for me to understand. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will increase your chances to get a meaningful response here, if you state what you have already tried to solve the problem yourself and post some artifacts (code, etc.) of such attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_nav_menu has a option to add classes or other attributes to ul by using items_wrap.

below is the code -

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu','menu'=>'Primary', 'items_wrap' => '<ul id="my-nav" class="navigation" role="navigation">%3$s</ul>'  ) );
```